# No module named 'pandas_datareader.mstar'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

I am using Python 3.6 (Anaconda) on Windows 10, PyCharm IDE. Please bear with me as I am new to coding. I just started Python for my equity research project.

Here is the code:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np

style.use('ggplot')

start=dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end=dt.datetime(2016,12,31)

df= web.DataReader('ERIE', 'google', start, end)

print(df.head())
```

It comes with an error, seems like this is an issue with pandas_datareader itself but I have no idea what is causing it. I checked "pip show pandas_datareader" in command shell and it is installed properly. Would really appreciate if someone can help me.

```
C:\Users\vtmin\Anaconda3\envs\untitled\python.exe "D:/PyCharm Projects/Stock Analysis/FinancePython.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm Projects/Stock Analysis/FinancePython.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
  File "C:\Users\vtmin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "C:\Users\vtmin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.mstar.daily import MorningstarDailyReader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader.mstar'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: try `conda install pandas-datareader` or `pip3 install pandas-datareader`

Comment: I tried conda install pandas-datareader. It is installed but the same error still pops up. I am not sure what is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I managed to resolve the error by deleting all yahoo related in the data.py (within the pandas-datareader package). Seems like there was an issue with the yahoo API, if I understand it correctly.